# Python UTF8 encoding 2.7.5 / 3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

What I try to understand is i'm runing Python 3.8.5 on Windows and Python 2.7.5 on my webserver.

i'm trying to translate from a JSON with a code like this

```
hash = ""
try:
    hash = str(translateTable[item["hash"]])
except:
hash = str(item["hash"])
```

the following code is loading the JSON file

```
with io.open('translate.json', encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    translateTable = json.load(fh)

JSON FILE {"vunk": "Vunk-Gerät"}
```

When I run the code on windows with 3.7.5 the result is like it should be

```
IN >>> python test.py
OUT>>> Vunk-Gerät
```

Here comes the tricky part, when I run on my webserver with Python 2.7.5 the result is this

```
IN >>> python test.py
OUT>>> vunk
```

The problem is, on the Webserver it can't translate "Ä,Ö,Ü,ß" and I don't get it why?

Comment: The problem as I said, is just on Python 2.7.5 Webserver. On Windows it works fine as it should be and this is what I don't get with the same code on each site.

Comment: Python 2.7 is end-of-life, end-of-support since january 2020 (announced in 2008). You're using software to develop 12 years ahead of what you intend to run on. Please use python 3.x, and don't make your life miserable chasing 12-year old bug fixes.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that the values loaded from the json object are `unicode` rather than `str`.  In Python 2 `unicode` is the equivalent of `str` in Python 3, and Python 2's `str` is the equivalent of Python 3's `bytes`.  So the problem may be:

```python
transtable = {u"vunk": u"Vunk-Gerät"}

str(transtable['vunk'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens because Python 2's `str` tries to encode `u"Vunk-Gerät"` to ascii, but it cannot (because of the "ä").

The simplest solution might be to avoid calling `str` at all:

```python
hash = ""
try:
    hash = translateTable[item["hash"]]
except Exception as ex:
    hash = item["hash"]
```

since the keys and values should be usable as they are.

A more robust approach would be to use the [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) library to handle string and bytes types in a way that works with both Python 2 and Python 3.  The ideal solution, as others have pointed out, is to run Python 3 on your server.  Python 3 is much easier to use when processing non-ASCII text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem without using str() it will result me the same error as you posted already.

Comment: That's because this error is inherently likely to occur when using Python 2 to handle non-ASCII strings, _unless_ the application is designed from the outset with this goal in mind.  Essentially, the use of `str` in Python 2 should be avoided as much as possible, usually by adopting the "unicode sandwich" technique.  And developers need to be aware of situations where Python 2 implicitly encodes values.  Anyway, it's good you've found a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is facing the same problem as me here is the solution for 2.7.5

```
from django.utils.six import smart_str, smart_unicode
```

```
hash = ""
try:
    hash = smart_str(translateTable[item["hash"]])
except Exception as ex:
    hash = smart_str(item["hash"])
```

also make sure django is installed

```
pip install django
```